# Highcharts chart triggers point or chart click event when user clicks on reset zoom button

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

It's very confusing because in our chart a popup opening happens when users click on the chart or the point and the popup opens when user clicks on reset zoom button. How do I resolve this? Any idea?

Comment: You need to post your jQuery code and a hyperlink to the exact plugin that you are using.

Comment: so the question is: how can I do that chart click or point click event  won't be triggered when I click to "reset zoom" button.

Comment: [point click](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-point-events-click/)

Comment: [series click](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/HLABa/)

Comment: @ruff Can you show your code to explain what's the problem ? I didn't understand your question.